# Textfield default color

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have code like this:

```
                VStack {
                    
                    ForEach(Array($ingredientNames.enumerated()), id:\.offset)  { (idx, $str) in
                        if idx != 0{
                            TextField("Player \(idx + 1)", text: $str)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .shadow(color: .white, radius: 20)
                                .background(Color("AccentColor"))
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                .font(Font.system(size: 26))
                        }
                        
                        else {
                            TextField("Player", text: $str)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .shadow(color: .white, radius: 20)
                                .background(Color("AccentColor"))
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                .font(Font.system(size: 26))
                        }
                    }
                }
```

But actually the color of "player" is gray (default). How can I make it for example white? Adding a .foregroundColor doesn't work as you can see - now it's working when user type something - then it's turning white. But how can I make it white as a default with no need to input something into this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Add this extension to your project:

```
extension View {
    func placeholder<Content: View>(
        when present: Bool,
        alignment: Alignment = .leading,
        @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) -> some View {

        ZStack(alignment: alignment) {
            content().opacity(present ? 1 : 0)
            self
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your code use this:

```
TextField("", text: $text)
    .placeholder(when: text.isEmpty) {
        Text("Player").foregroundColor(.white)
    }
    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    .fontWeight(.bold)
    .shadow(color: .white, radius: 20)
    .background(Color("AccentColor"))
    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
    .font(Font.system(size: 26))
```